# How to convert images to video in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, video-encoding

I am developing an IP Camera application in Windows Phone 7. My requirements are to record the video and save it to the local path. I can already access the images through the IP Camera API, and now I want to convert the images to video. How should I do that?

Comment: What is the reason for giving negative vote.. please give the valuable reason here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure sample code for this exact task exists.  You may start by looking at the [System.Windows.Media](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608873%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) docs, in particularly `VideoRecorder`, `CaptureSource` and `FileSink`.  The [How to: Record Video in a Camera Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394041%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) article and [Video Recorder Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Video-Recorder-Sample-5e800bbf) may also be useful.  I understand that you are not trying to encode video from the camera, but these examples show how to access the available encoders on the phone, you just need to figure out how to give them your own video frames.  One problem I can see is that `CaptureSource`, `FileSink` and `VideoCaptureDevice` are all sealed classes.  Normally `FileSink` calls [CaptureSource.CaptureImageAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.capturesource.captureimageasync%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and gets the next frame as a `WriteableBitmap` as a property in the [CaptureSource.CaptureImageCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.capturesource.captureimagecompleted%28v=vs.96%29.aspx) event handler.  This is where you would want to provide the frames you have, but how?  You cannot inherit from `CaptureSource`... if you could you would simply set that as the source to the file sink and provide your own frames.  So at a glance it is not clear whether you can even encode your own video using the built-in codecs on Windows Phone.

Another approach if you can use open-source codecs is to compile ffmpeg (or gstreamer, or xuggler, or x264, ...).  You might check out [ffmpeg4pocketpc](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=579384), I don't know much about it but looks promising.  Or, pick up a commercial codec library such as CoreCodec.

Comment: ive done similar things on the desktop with C#. Is it possible to use a direct show filter chain because if it is, i highly recommend that.

Comment: http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/2009/05/20/monogram-x264-encoder-1050/ is a open source x264 encoder direct show filter if you go that route, he also has some super useful codecs/filters if you go the direct show route.